# The keyboard does not open when I edit a textfield on my Flutter Web application with voiceOVer

Tags: flutter, dart, web, textfield, flutter-web

When using VoiceOver to access the application's TextField in a mobile browser, the keyboard does not open. Do you have a solution for this ?

```
Widget _searchTextField() => SizedBox(
        width: 275,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: TextField(
              focusNode: _focus,
              onChanged: (text) => _searchText.add(text),
              decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: "Rechercher")),
        ),
      );
```